# uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property value of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Cannot set property 'currentLat' of null; I tried declaring all the variables globally so I can use the later but I don't know why I keep getting null when I call a variable and try to set its properties.

```
currentLat: any;
 currentLng: any;

  ngOnInit() {
        this.watchPosition();
      }

 watchPosition() {
        var options = {
            maximumAge: 3600000,
            timeout: 3000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
        }
        var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        function onSuccess(position) {
            this.currentLat=position.coords.latitude;
            this.currentLng=position.coords.longitude ;
        };

        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
    }
```

Comment: And i can't find `actualLocation` in your code anywhere. will you post relevant code please.

Comment: i updated my code please see once

Comment: Simply this is not available in this context. Read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not available in your nested function. You can bind `this` like `onSuccess.bind(this);` to the function or easily assign `this` to another variable.

```
watchPosition() {
  const that = this;
  const options = {
    maximumAge: 3600000,
    timeout: 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  };

  const watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
  function onSuccess(position) {
    that.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    that.currentLng = position.coords.longitude ;
  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions to access "this" variable:

```
onSuccess = (position) => {
    this.currentLat=position.coords.latitude;
    this.currentLng=position.coords.longitude ;
}
```

Comment: what is this is this answer to my queston?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this`is null since you are using it inside the function. You could use ***arrow functions*** instead.

```
 watchPosition() {
        var options = {
            maximumAge: 3600000,
            timeout: 3000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
        }
        var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        onSuccess = (position) => {
            this.currentLat=position.coords.latitude;
            this.currentLng=position.coords.longitude ;
        };

        onError = (error) => {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
    }
```

Comment: implementing `arrow functions` in that way, you'll got an error in typescript `Cannot find name [functionName]`